# I want to display css notifications based on java script value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display css notifications based on javascript values. But, it shows all the notifications currently, and I want to add the javascript value to notification box.

This is my javascript method

```js
    var colorBox = function() {

      alert("myValues" + myValues);


      //document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box error').innerHTML=myValues[0];;
      var myValues = [100];

      if (myValues[0] < 70) {

        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box success');



      } else if (myValues >= 51 && myValues.value < 70) {
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box error');

      } else if (myValues <= 50) {
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box warning');

      }
    }
    colorBox();
```

```html
<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Write your error message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box success"><span>success: </span>Write your success message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box warning"><span>warning: </span>Write your warning message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box notice"><span>notice: </span>Write your notice message here.</div>
```

Comment: You mentioned, its displaying all results, Yes its display all results because you are not hiding and result.

Comment: What do want to do? The question is not clear!

Comment: i want to to hide the other notifications if condition fails  if (myValues[0] < 70) {

       document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box success').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hidden` attribute to hide all alert containers initially and then remove the `hidden` attribute when the alert shall be displayed.

```js
var colorBox = function(value) {

  if (value < 70) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box success')[0];
    container.removeAttribute('hidden');
  } else if (value >= 51 && value < 70) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box error')[0];
    container.removeAttribute('hidden');
  } else if (value <= 50) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-box warning')[0];
    container.removeAttribute('hidden');
  }
}

colorBox(50); // or any other value
```

```html
<div class="alert-box error" hidden><span>error: </span>Write your error message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box success" hidden><span>success: </span>Write your success message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box warning" hidden><span>warning: </span>Write your warning message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box notice" hidden><span>notice: </span>Write your notice message here.</div>
```

Comment: If you're passing `colorBox(50);` , then it should show `alert-box warning`, because its under `else if (value <= 50)` condition.

Comment: I am getting an error saying undefined attribute hidden

Comment: Its working here though,but not working in my editor weird

Comment: @abhishek-pandey: Actually, the last `if` condition will never be passed as the first one will always be valid, too. However, I left it there so that the code is not altered too much.

Comment: @jowy have you added the `hidden` attribute to each `div` element?